# C# Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook Getting Owner of Distribution Group

Tags: c#, outlook

I am trying to get a list of distribution groups a user owns in Outlook. I see how to get the groups a user is a member of (see below), but cannot find anywhere about ownership. I know this is possible using Active Directory, but want to be able to use Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook library instead. I want to be able to have the user select a group from the list he/she owns, and modify the members.

```
private void GetCurrentUserMembership()
    {
        var appOutlook = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application();
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AddressEntry currentUser = appOutlook.Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry;
        if (currentUser.Type == "EX")
        {
            Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.ExchangeUser exchUser = currentUser.GetExchangeUser();
            if (exchUser != null)
            {
                Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AddressEntries addrEntries = exchUser.GetMemberOfList();
                if (addrEntries != null)
                {
                    foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.AddressEntry addrEntry in addrEntries)
                    {
                        Debug.WriteLine(addrEntry.Name);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: `I know this is possible using Active Directory`.  All things being equal (and understanding you probably have your own good reasons for choosing the legacy Interop libraries), Active Directory is *EXACTLY* what I'd recommend.  Specifically, [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have not tried that with DLs, but try to retrieve `PR_EMS_AB_ASSOC_NT_ACCOUNT` (DASL name `http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x80270102`) using `AddressEntry.PropertyAccessor.GetProperty`. You can then try to use the SID to look up the user.